# Print output when button is pressed and there is a segue - Xcode Swift Apple Watch?

Tags: swift, xcode, segue, apple-watch

I want to print something onto the output when a button is pressed that will also trigger a push `segue`.

When a button is pressed I want to change the value of `variable1` to a number and then have that print that to the output.

This works fine when there is no push segue afterwards but it doesn't work when the button will also trigger a push segue.

This is my code at the moment:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed() {

    var variable1 = "easy"
    print(variable1)

}
```

I am trying to do this on an Apple Watch in Xcode.

Comment: Sorry, I was typing the correct thing into Xcode and I just copied it over wrong. Have you got any other suggestions?

Comment: So you mean that when you make a push then `buttonPressed` is not called and when you don´t have a push then it´s called?

Comment: That's correct @RashwanL

Comment: Ok got it now, I´ll post an answer for you.

Comment: Ok, thanks @RashwanL.

Comment: Sorry I'm just on my way out so can only leave a quick comment but I think you need to look into implementing `func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` on your view controller.  This will be called when the segue is run.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth I Have multiple segues though that each needs to do different actions when pressed.

Comment: You can use the segues identifier to differentiate between them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a "regular" app project target you can both `segue` from and connect an `IBAction`from a button. This does not seems to work on a WatchKit application.

What you need to do is to remove the `IBAction` and the add the following method:

```
override func contextForSegue(withIdentifier segueIdentifier: String) -> Any? {
    if segueIdentifier == "someId" {
        var variable1 = "easy"
        print(variable1)
        return ...
    }
    return ...
}
```

Add a identifier to your segue and check for it in the `contextForSegue` method and print out the values in there instead.

**Return Value**
The object to pass to the new interface controller. Use this object to communicate important information to the new interface controller, such as the data to be displayed or any relevant state information. You may return nil if you want, but doing so is not recommended.